# Does US law permit spending taxpayers' money to support foreign political parties?

Tags: united-states, russia, contemporary-history

Here is a video, showing a number of Russian opposition activists visiting U.S. embassy before Russian presidential elections:

http://www.youtube.com/v/yf3LjntNX20?version=3&feature=player_detailpage

On way back they all say a completely identical phrase to the camera (actually held by an amauter) "You are Surkov's propaganda" (Surkov is a Putin's deputy)

It is known that U.S. openly supports Russian opposition.

Thus my question is whether it is permitted in the US to spend the taxpayers' money to support pro-US parties in foreign countries?

If so, whether it is permitted for a currently ruling party in the US to spend the state money to support their own political agenda abroad?

How this was arranged formerly and whether there were any political or judicial controversies about this issue?

Comment: FYI, Surkov is no longer Putin's deputy. He's now in charge of stealing money.... errr.... heading the research into nanotechnology. Previously, he was the main ideological theorist of Putin regime.

Comment: How is this question historical?  It deals with current law.

Comment: @DVK he exactly his deputy, Putin is premier and Surkov is vice-premier.

Comment: @DavidThornley there are historical precedents for this, the US has supported pro-US governments in other countries through foreign aid.  It's not a new idea and has been going on since the 1950's with the Cold War.

Comment: @Anixx - Sorry, I was treating Putin as President (still/already) :)

Comment: @MichaelF:  A question on what money the US has spent supporting pro-US parties and where would be on topic.  A question of current legality would not be.  Currently, the last sentence, which isn't the original question, is on topic.

Comment: @DavidThornley I don't see the question as pure legality, and it has some historical context in American diplomacy, so either way it's fine the way it is.

Comment: Where are any proofs that the opposition got money from USA?
The whole press, all TV channels, is controlled by Putin. Where is that info from? From the press, controlled by Putin? Oppositions leaders are literate enough to never say the phrase cited in the question. It is not history already, it is the pure politics and very dirty one. And moderators should stop that trolling question rather than to stop any negative reaction to it.

Comment: I wouldn't take @Gangnus 's extra step of censoring the question, but he's absoultely right about the rest. I really dislike the rhetorical trick of hand-waving the weakest part of your thesis away by prefacing it with "It's known that...".

Comment: Well "American state department has promised to Russian oppositioners more than 9 million dollars in 2012. National Endowment for Democracy already supports non-governmental organizations in Russia for a long time. Other foundatons also take part in it" Russian: http://inosmi.ru/politic/20120203/184771326.html French original: http://mondialisation.ca/index.php?context=va&aid=29048

Comment: Note that National Endowment for Democracy is a state-funded organization according to their web site: http://www.ned.org/ In this page: http://www.ned.org/where-we-work/eurasia they describe that they support Russian peaceful protests, the "31" movement and the "Solidarity" movement.

Comment: Maxim Petrovich, the member of the political council of the Solidarity movement has recently exposed how they get money from the USA. He said the scheme was simple: the State Department gives money to "non-government organizations" USAID and NED hundreds million dollars "for support of democracy". The word "non-government" should be quoted according to him because the bodies exist only because of state funding and realize state programs. These organizations then fund IRI and NDI institutions which transfer money to the opposition. He explains extensively and shows typical "donation" contracts.

Comment: Link for the above comment: http://www.rus-obr.ru/ru-web/15973

Comment: In this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=PE3LY1giUNo which became widely known in Russia Lev Ponomarev, another member of "Solidarnost" polit-council has a conversation with a Japanese diplomat. He said openly that Americans government foundations, created, as he said, by State Department, give money to him and his movement. They fund him, as he said. He says that currently only the US foundations give him money. He similarly asks for a grant from the Japanese, promising support for transfer of the disputed Kuril islands to Japan.

Comment: The funny part is that it recently came to light that USAID was also "giving money" (i.e. organizing all kinds of seminars and training courses) to Putin's party, United Russia. Guess what - USAID actually acts on its avowed principles.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg possibly it was designed so. I think they conduct propagandist activities among many influential parties abroad. Giving propagandist seminars is not the same as giving money directly though

Comment: @Anixx: The difference is not that big as you think. Those oh-so-nefarious-grants are, as far as I understand, given for specific projects. Anyway, there is a veritable witch-hunt picking up steam in Russia and the accusations you refer to are a part of it...

Comment: "as far as I understand, given for specific projects" - for example, making unrests and revolutions. Or (posssibly) for adopting certain legislation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is politics not history

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Could we place a historical "lock" on this question. It was acceptable in an earlier incarnation of History SE (e.g. before the advent of Politics SE), but would be off topic today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The US does provide money abroad for humanitarian reasons, although I am sure some money can go through certain channels (or agencies) and find it's way to foreign political parties that are pro-US.  This is certainly the case with governments which receive funds from the US in order to keep the party in power, or certainly influence a pro-US point of view.  It happens, has happened and in many ways is legal as it's money spent under Foreign Aid, although it is becoming a political topic now that the US is heading into elections and our budget can't readily support such subsidies.  If there are political parties being given money I don't know, but it probably happens and in many cases is probably done so it's untracable.

Political parties in power in the US do give money to support parts of their agenda, the most recent example I can think of is the Bush Administration stopped giving aid money to organizations that promoted abortion.

There are controversies, but many either blow over when a scandal comes up, or a new Administration comes to power and then reverts any foreign aid assistance guidelines imposed by the previous administration.

Comment: Is it legal to give money to US parties and politicians from the state budget through some programs? For example, can Democratic party start a government program "to support democracy" that indirectly (through say, Freedom House) gives money to itself?

Answer (score 7):

Just as an interesting contra-discussion, the Alien and Sedition Acts of 1798 were largely influenced by the French government's desire to fund Jefferson during the election of 1796. Foreign governments have been involved in elections for a long time.

Comment: Very true, it does go back quite a ways back and forth so it's not just the US that has done this.

Comment: @AffableGeek - True, but that's a different issue. It is quite illegal in the USA for political campaigns to accept money from foriegn donors. However, its perfectly legal in the USA for USA donors to *give* donations to foriegn campaigns (as long as it isn't a direct bribe, which would be illegal). Still, most countries have as dim a view of receiving such gifts as ours does, so doing this directly is probably not a good way to help the cause of someone you support.

Comment: @T.E.D. What law prohibits foreign donors from giving to American political campaigns? Indeed, it would run counter to the Buckley decision to make a law to this effect.  The right to contribute to a campaign is protected free speech.

Comment: @AffableGeek - Nope. Foriegn nationals who are not permanent residents are barred by federal law from donating directly, or even spending on their own in USA political campaigns. The Supremes specificaly upheld this even after Citizens United (see Bluman, et al., v. Federal Election Commission). Of course the question after CU is how they can be stopped, since such funds can now be funneled through groups that are not required to disclose their donors.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make distinctions between:

- US government openly supporting a group (likely, not happening though for reasons of plausible deniability/optics rather than some law). This may be confused with legit spending on assorted humanitarian etc... programs though. The latter is legal as long as Congress appropriates the money for the purpose.
- US government clandestinely supporting a group - e.g. via CIA. This is legal AFAIK, as long as all the bureaucratic ass-covering is done.
- US non-governmental organizations doing this (in case of Russia, Soros seemed to be a big sugar daddy in 1990s/2000s). DEFINITELY not coordinated with US govt in case of Soros in 2000s, since Soros is politically a mortal enemy of GW Bush. Totally legal as long as one doesn't run afoul of anti-bribery/anti-corruption laws.

Comment: I meant state funds spent on opposition groups (or on groups with certain ideology).

Comment: Any of the 3 options above can and has been spent on those.

Comment: +1, although the Soros/Bush thing was unnessecary (and arguably untrue).

Answer (score 1):

USA spent many time and money to win in the "cold" war, now USA just changed ways to protect their interests in Russia (main exUSSR country). Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cnsnews.com/blog/michael-w-chapman/state-dept-350k-group-built-campaign-structure-used-against-election-israels

> According to the U.S. Senate Permanent Subcommittee on Investigations
>   (PSI), the State Department gave $349,276 in U.S. taxpayer-funded
>   grants to a political group in Israel to build a campaign operation,
>   which subsequently was used to try to influence Israelis to vote
>   against conservative Benjamin Netanyahu in the March 2015 election for
>   prime minister.
>
> In the Permanent Subcommittee on Investigations report about the State
>   Department’s action, Chairman Bob Portman (R-Ohio) said, “It is
>   completely unacceptable that U.S. taxpayer dollars were used to build
>   a political campaign infrastructure that was deployed — immediately
>   after the grant ended — against the leader [Netanyahu] of our closest
>   ally in the Middle East.  American resources should be used to help
>   our allies in the region, not undermine them.”

Usually it wouldn't be directly, people don't like outsiders influencing politics, from the "A Call for Unity" letter by Southern clergy against Martin Luther King Jr., to accusations by the Bolsheviks against the White armies.

But the US has funded foreign political groups to influence elections to get a party elected.

Comment: This says nothing about US law, so doesn't answer the question. (Which in a way is fortunate, as it allows us to avoid the issue of how its entirely sourced from a partisan propaganda outlet with shady finances).